# How do you add CSJS like XSP.partialRefreshGet to onComplete event of an eventHandler?

Tags: xpages

I have an event handler on a button that runs some SSJS code which updates a viewScope variable. I am using partial refresh and have selected the ID I want to refresh. However, in the onComplete event of the event handler I want to update another ID. The onComplete event appears to only accept SSJS. How do you add CSJS to the onComplete event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onComplete event (as well as onStart and onError) accepts csjs, not ssjs.  So you should be able to add an XSP.partialRefreshGet() call which will perform a partial refresh after your initial partial refresh.

Comment: After adding the onComplete as an attribute to the xp:eventHandler tag it did in fact work with CSJS. There appears to be a bug in Designer because when I add the code to the onComplete via the All Properties it writes the onComplete as a <xp:this.onComplete> complex property to the event handler and then produces a runtime error saying XSP object is not defined.